# Does every infinite-dimensional Banach algebra contain an infinite-dimensional subalgebra with second-countable primitive ideal space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras, ideals

Let $A$ be an infinite dimensional Banach algebra.  Even if separable the primitive ideal space of $A$ need not be second-countable when endowed with the hull-kernel topology. Can we at least find an infinite-dimensional subalgebra with this property?

For C*-algebras, separability implies second-countable primitive ideal space.

Comment: Got it, I'll think about the new version then.

Comment: Does every infinite dimensional Banach algebra contain an infinite dimensional abelian subalgebra? That would reduce this to the abelian case.

Comment: @NikWeaver, yes, that's true.

Thomas J. Laffey, Commutative subalgebras of infinite dimensional algebras, Bull. London Math. Soc.,5 (1973), 312-314.

Comment: Perhaps I'm writing the obvious at this point. If $A$ is (WLOG unital) commutative and separable, then its image $\Gamma(A)$ under the Gelfand map $\Gamma$ is a separable subalgebra of $C(\sigma(A))$ that separates the points of $\sigma(A)$ and contains the constants. Thus, by Stone-Weierstrass theorem, $\Gamma(A)$ is dense in $C(\sigma(A))$, and so $C(\sigma(A))$ is separable.

Comment: @OnurOktay, I am asking about the hull-kernel topology, not the Gelfand topology.

Comment: Tomek: it seems from discussions below (and some reading I was doing of an old paper of Feinstein+Somerset) that the disc algebra might be a counterexample to the question you posed. However, I am not sure that we actually have a proof yet.

Comment: Updated version of the answer looks much better, but I haven't gone through it in full-on referee mode:)

Comment: Sir, you're formidable opponent when you're in a full referee mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no.
Let $A=A(D)$ be the [disk algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_algebra). Every character on $A$ is a point evaluation at some $x\in D_1$, the closed unit disk of $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ of $A$ is $D_1$. Let $D_r = \{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|\leq r\}$ for $r<1$. Then, the restriction of the hull-kernel topology on $\sigma(A)$ to $D_r$ is cofinite topology. In fact, if $S\subseteq D_r$ is not finite, then $k(S) = \{0\}$, so $h(k(S)) = \sigma(A)$. Consequently, the hull-kernel topology on $\sigma(A)$ is not even first countable.

Second, let $B\subseteq A$ be an infinite-dimensional closed subalgebra of $A$. Pick an $r<1$ and define an equivalence relation on $D_r$ via
$$x\sim y \Leftrightarrow f(x) = f(y)\hspace{8mm} \forall f\in B.$$
By the basic properties of analytic functions, it is not difficult to show that the equivalence classes of $\sim$ are at most finite. Thus, $D_r/\sim$ is an uncountable set. Moreover, $D_r/\sim \subseteq\sigma(B)$. Proceeding the same as above, the restriction of the hull-kernel topology on $\sigma(B)$ to $D_r/\sim$ is the cofinite topology. We conclude that the hull-kernel topology on $\sigma(B)$ is not even first countable.

On the positive side, if a commutative Banach algebra $A$ contains a separable *regular* (some sources use "completely regular" rather than "regular") subalgebra $B$, then the hull-kernel topology on $\sigma(B)$ is second countable. The reason for this is the fact that the Gelfand topology and the hull-kernel topology coincide on a spectrum of a regular Banach algebra, e.g. [Theorem 3.2.10](https://books.google.ca/books?id=RHGqvwEACAAJ&pg=PA326) in [Palmer, "Banach Algebras and the General Theory of *-Algebras I"]. Clearly, the Gelfand topology of a separable Banach algebra is second countable.

Finally, I think the following related note might be useful although it is not asked in the question. Let $F=\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a countable subset of $D$ that has an accumulation point in $D$. Let $V=\{(f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}} : f\in A(D)\}$ with the norm adopted from $A(D)$. Then, the map $f\to(f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ maps $A(D)$ isomorphically onto $V$, where $\sigma(V)$ is countable. Thus, the hull-kernel topology on $\sigma(V)$ is second countable. Paraphrasing, there exists countable subsets $F\subseteq\sigma{(A(D))}$, which are dense in $\sigma(A(D))$ in the hull-kernel topology of $\sigma(A(D))$, and for which the restriction of the hull-kernel topology to $F$ is second countable.

Comment: Let me try again. Regarding your comment https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413540/does-every-infinite-dimensional-banach-algebra-contain-an-infinite-dimensional-s/413755?noredirect=1#comment1060973_413755 I still do not understand in what sense you are providing "an affirmative answer with an extra condition." Please edit your answer to write down a clear statement "Every inf-dim BA [with extra condition] contains an inf-dim subalgebra with second-countable primitive ideal space"

Comment: Secondly: I am aware of the fact that a non-constant analytic function on an open domain in the complex plane cannot have accumulating zeroes in that domain. However, if we let $S=\{ 1- 1/n^2 \colon n\in {\bf N} \}$, then I think that there is a function in A(D) whose zero set is exactly $\{1\}\cup S$; consequently $\{1\}\cup S$ is a hull-kernel-closed subset of $\bar{D}$, and in the relative HK-topology on D, S is a countably infinite closed set.

Comment: Thirdly, your comment https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413540/does-every-infinite-dimensional-banach-algebra-contain-an-infinite-dimensional-s/413755?noredirect=1#comment1060976_413755 misunderstands my point. I am well aware that point evaluations of the form ${\rm ev}_x$, $x\in D$, will define characters on B. However, it is quite possible that different points of D will define the same character on B: consider $x=\pm 1/2$ and take B to be the subalgebra generated by 1 and $z^2$. So we only have a function $D \to B$, not an embedding

Comment: Fourthly, you haven't answered my question about what $D\setminus \sigma(B)$ is supposed to mean. If $X,Y$ are subsets of some set $\Omega$ then to me $X\setminus Y = X \cap (\Omega\setminus Y)$. Your previous comments seem to merely say that there is a function from D to $\sigma(B)$, so how I can consider "points of D not in $\sigma(B)$"?

Comment: @YemonChoi To be precise, let $B^{\perp}\subseteq (A(D))^*$ be the annihilator of $B$. Then, $ev_D/B^{\perp}$ is a subset of $\sigma(B)$. Let's define an equivalence relation on $D$ by $z_1\sim z_2$ iff $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$ for all $f\in B$. Let $D_r\subseteq D$ be the disk of radius $r<1$ centered at $0$. Let $\overline{z}$ denote the equivalence class of $z\in D$. Then, $\overline{z}\cap D_r$ can be at most finite. Perhaps one can also prove that  $\overline{z}\cap D_r$ have the same number of elements except $z$ for which $ev_z\in B^{\perp}$.

Comment: Let's replace $D$ by $D_r$ for some $r<1$. The restriction of HK-topology on the spectrum of $A(D)$ to the subset $D_r$ is surely the cofinite topology. This still implies that the HK-topology on the spectrum of $A(D)$ is not first countable.

Comment: Perhaps the statement I can provide is weaker than you suggest: If a Banach algebra $A$ possess a separable regular subalgebra $B$, then the HK-topology on $\sigma(B)$ is second countable.

Comment: Another crucial point I should make is the following: Choose a countable subset $F=\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subseteq D$ that has an accumulation point in $D$. Then, the map $f\to (f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ maps $A(D)$ isomorphically onto an algebra with second countable HK-topology on its spectrum.  Such subsets of the spectrum must be called sets of uniqueness as far as I can remember, please correct if it's wrong. Paraphrasing, there exists countable subsets $F$ of the spectrum of $A(D)$ that uniquely define the algebra $A(D)$, and for which the restriction of the HK-topology is 2nd countable